# AngularJS date filter incorrect time

Tags: datetime, angularjs, timezone

I have a date object formatted to isotime. I'm using the |date filter to nicely format this in my template, but it incorrectly changing the time.

This Code...

```
    <td>[[ user.last_online | date:'dd MMM yyyy - hh:mm a' ]]</td>
    <td>[[ user.last_online ]]</td>
```

Results in this...

[image]

Now I know that the 1 hour difference is because of the Timezone, this is what I'm expecting. The Minutes however is incorrect.

In the first row, 13 minutes gets added when the filter is applied.
In the second row, 5 minutes gets added.

Not only are these two values wrong, but they are also inconsistent.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See [this simple Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/srnug/). What's the javascript value (`console.log`) of `user.last_online` ?

Comment: Can you paste your isotime ?

Comment: The 2nd column is the exact value for last_online, and is the isoformat() result returned by python's datetime module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check ISO8601, you can see the correct time stamp format is

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ
```

The milliseconds should consists of 3 digits. I did a simple test and you can see after correcting the milliseconds part, the dates will be rendered correctly.

```
{{"2013-08-09T15:36:31.764546+02:00" | date:'dd MMM yyyy - hh:mm a'}}<br />
{{"2013-08-09T15:34:14.318753+02:00" | date:'dd MMM yyyy - hh:mm a'}}<br />
{{"2013-08-09T15:36:31.764+02:00" | date:'dd MMM yyyy - hh:mm a'}}<br />
{{"2013-08-09T15:34:14.318+02:00" | date:'dd MMM yyyy - hh:mm a'}}<br />
```

The result is

```
09 Aug 2013 - 09:49 AM
09 Aug 2013 - 09:39 AM
09 Aug 2013 - 09:36 AM
09 Aug 2013 - 09:34 AM
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6cW3h/)**</kbd>

**Update**

Python's `datetime.isoformat()` return the time with microseconds `0 <= microsecond < 1000000`. Angularjs doesn't like, though this format is correct according to ISO8601, since ISO8601 only requires `one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second`

So I guess you can use `strftime` to format it.

Comment: This does indeed look like it's the problem. I am however using pythons datetime.isoformat() to get that format and it returns it as you see in the 2nd column.

Comment: looks like I'll have to format the result from that method to drop the extra digits in the miliseconds.

Comment: @sza - The number of decimals in ISO8601 is variable.  It's just a bug in Angular. See my answer.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks! Hopefully they can get this fixed ASAP. But in the meantime, this should be an alternative.

Comment: I'm going to mark this one as the solution, since this did fix the problem. However, as @MattJohnson pointed out in his answer, the real issue is a bug within the angular version I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

I think the value of `user.last_online` is incorrect or has a bad format. If you check [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), you can see the correct time stamp format is:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ
```

<kbd>**[My plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/si4CyM1BloRMv2XZSc1t)**</kbd>

Comment: The number of decimals in ISO8601 is variable. It's just a bug in Angular. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your dates are correctly formatted.  ISO8601 doesn't actually require any particular number of decimals.  There could be anywhere from zero to 7 decimals or more.  If you look at an actual copy of the ISO8601 spec, section 4.2.2.4 says the following:

> ... with as many digits as necessary following the decimal sign ...

There are a few older browsers where this mattered when passed directly to the `new Date()` constructor, but AFAIK those were consider bugs and were fixed.

You are experiencing a bug in AngularJS, which was fixed in version 1.1.5.  You can find it referenced in their [change log](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) as follows:

> date filter: correctly format dates with more than 3 sub-second digits ([4f2e3606](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/4f2e36068502f18814fee0abd26951124881f951))